# Exchange 2003 System Attendant mailbox gone

Tags: exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003

after moving the mailboxes from the old to the new server, the system attendant mailbox is gone.

The old server isn´t in network. So do you know a way to recover or renew the system attendant mailbox?

Thanks for help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Every Exchange server has its own System Attendant mailbox, and it can't be moved to another server; the mailbox is is automatically created on the default first mailbox database when a server is installed; if that database is later deleted, the mailbox may disappear and not get created again on another database.

The suggested resolution is to use ADSIEdit to modify the Active Directory attribute which defines where the System Attendant mailbox should be stored:

http://smarthost.blogspot.it/2007/06/test-post.html

Comment: Thanks for help but it doesnt work :/